# Updating docker compose to 1.8 on windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, blockchain, hyperledger

I have freshly installed Docker community edition on windows because i need to run a hyperledger blockchain locally on my machine. However even though it was freshly installed the docker-compose version 1.14. I need to have docker-compose 1.8 to run the hyperledger blockchain according the documentation i got from the hyperledger getting started guide. I searched for ways to update the docker-compose version on windows to docker-compose version 1.8, but i haven't found a solid way to do that. Can someone enlighten me on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command in elevated Powershell in Windows 10.

run the following command to download Docker Compose, replacing $dockerComposeVersion with the specific version of Compose you want to use:

Invoke-WebRequest "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$dockerComposeVersion/docker-compose-Windows-x86_64.exe" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile $Env:ProgramFiles\docker\docker-compose.exe

For Eg:

For example, to download Compose version 1.22.0, the command is:

Invoke-WebRequest "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-Windows-x86_64.exe" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile $Env:ProgramFiles\docker\docker-compose.exe

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused between *docker compose version* and *docker compose file version*. Just update the docker-compose file version and you will be good to go. [enter link description here](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases)